# R packages for symbolic regression

Tags: r, symbolic-math

I want to carry out a symbolic regression with R. The rgp package is the most recommended package on the internet but it was removed from CRAN.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgp/index.html

Does anybody know some other equivalent packages in R?

Comment: Does it work for you to download the git version: https://github.com/cran/rgp/blob/master/R/symbolic_regression.r ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me how to download the git version? I tried install_github("cran/rgp") but it doesn't work(Same issue when i tried to install locally the downloaded package from achieve). I tried also to paste the symbolic_regression.r code in R, but "dataDrivenGeneticProgramming" can not be found.

Comment: I've updated an answer. I think that you can find everything you need in there. Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative package is the `gramEvol` package (on CRAN).

I wrote a blog post about it with several examples:
 https://blog.ephorie.de/symbolic-regression-genetic-programming-or-if-kepler-had-r

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so you can download `rgp` from the (unofficial) repository of CRAN at github.com

You should start trying the [git](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) tool to do it. This way, once you've installed it, you can clone the repository with:

```
git clone https://github.com/cran/rgp.git
```

In the `R/` folder of the repository (the local copy that you've downloaded or in the very [github website of the rgp package](https://github.com/cran/rgp)) you should see all functions of the package, as `.R` files.

Other way to use these functions would be to build (`R CMD build`) the package, install it (`install.packages("builtrepo.tgz",repos=NULL,type="source")`) and load (with `require` or `include`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but neither of them works. I prefer to try out the second one but when i install the package, it shows :  Warning: invalid package 'builtrepo.tgz'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
In R CMD INSTALL

Comment: This is because you havent built the package, or you are not referring to it by its current name. You sould write someting like `R CMD build rgp` in the directory where you downloaded the repo. You might need to install additional dependencies. Then, when you actually build the package, you should see its name (perhaps `rgp.tar.gz`, the name in the responde was just an example). Then you're done, you can install it

Comment: Any way, I don't understand why copying the `.R` functions in the git package doesn't work for you. Any function you used from that package should be right there.

Comment: Because i just copied one of them(symbolic_regression.R) and i need to copy all the other .R functions for building the whole rgp package. Any way thank you for these answers it is helpful !